# Align numbers in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to print a multiplication table in C# but it's not aligned!
When we type a number "n" in textbox means: n*n table.
What can I do?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); j++)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i * j) + " ";
    }
    richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using tab instead of space. `richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i * j) + "\t";`

Comment: Set the font of `RichTextBox` to `Courier New`, then add the text to `RichTextBox` by padding the result of multiplication: this.richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0,3}", i * j));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the font of [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to the monospaced font `Courier New`, then add the text to `RichTextBox` using [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and setting alignment for the result of multiplication. Use a positive number to align right and use a negative number to align left:

```
var n = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0,3}", i * j));
    }
    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Instead of format the result by `{0,3}` you can use below code to format based on maximum length of characters is a number which belongs to `n*n`:

**Left Aligned:**

```
string.Format("{0,-" +((n*n).ToString().Length + 1).ToString() +"}", i * j)
```

[image]

**Right Aligned:**

```
string.Format("{0," +((n*n).ToString().Length + 1).ToString() +"}", i * j)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align using spaces, you need to use a monospaced font (like Courier, or Consolas), otherwise you can use tabs: numbers won't be aligned this way though, and since numbers in your routine can get considerably big, you may end up having your numbers occupy more than the tab separation, and will get inconsistencies in the alignment if that happens.

As a general rule, if you want to align any kind of text box, go with a monospaced font.

You can pad with spaces, using, for example, `String.PadLeft` or `String.PadRight`.

This would be as simple as changing:

```
richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i * j) + " ";
```

With

```
richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i * j).PadLeft(5);
```

However this would assume all numbers are at maximum 5 characters in width.

For your precise routine, you could calculate the maximum width though, so you'd end up with something like:

```
 // convert your input only once
 int myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 // pad with the maximum possible length, plus one space
 int padAmount = (myNumber * myNumber).ToString().Length + 1; 
 for (int i = 1; i <= myNumber; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 1; j <= myNumber; j++)
   {
     // pad your input by the amount of spaces needed to fit all possible numbers
     richTextBox1.Text += (i*j).ToString().PadLeft(padAmount);
   }
 }
 // use Environment.NewLine instead of `\n`
 richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZahSly). It's (for obvious reasons) for console, so in my fiddle the input number is fixed (it's in `myNumber`) and the output is just a string (instead of `richTextBox1.Text`), but it should show how it works.

Although I've made a few changes (I only convert the input number once, and use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`), this is far from optimal though, you should build your string (using a `StringBuilder`) and assign it at once, instead of adding to the `Text` property. I've made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgVrOW) with this approach, and memory consumption has gone down by over 30mb (to just a handful of kb) just by using  `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using a tab instead of a special font and padding with white spaces.

For tabs you must add a `"\t"` after every number. The `"\t"` will be evaluated as an *tab*-character.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); j++)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i * j) + "\t "; //here at the end
    }
    richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
}
```

But it is important, that a tab has a fixed width. In case your numbers are too long, you need 2 tabs for short numbers. But for small tables like yours it is no problem.

[image: Screenshot with standard tab size]

You can change the position of the tabs with the `SelectionTabs` property:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionTabs = new[] { 20, 40, 60, 80 };
```

[image: Screenshot with customized tab size]

**BTW**, you should use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate multiple string parts to one. And it would be more effective to parse the number from textBox1 only once and not during every iteration.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(); //In namespace System.Text
var x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //parse only once 
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++)
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(i * j));
        sb.Append("\t ");
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
}
richTextBox1.Text += sb.ToString();
```